# Is position inside a defined 3d cylinder

Tags: 3d, lua

"pos" is a 3d coordinate that IS inside the cylinder.

"pos2" is a 3d coordinate that is NOT inside the cylinder.

However when running my code below, it determines that both are outside the cylinder. Is there something wrong with the math behind my "ContainsVector" function?

For readability reasons, here is the same code in hastebin: http://hastebin.com/giquwomuko.lua

```lua
Vector3 = {
    new = function(x0, y0, z0)
        return {x = x0, y = y0, z = z0}
    end
}


CylinderRegion = {
    New = function(self, center, height, r)
        return {
            Center = center;
            Bottom = center.y - height / 2;
            Top = center.y + height / 2;
            Radius = r;
            Height = height;
            Volume = math.pi * r^2 * height;
            PrintProperties = function(self)
                for prop, val in pairs(self) do
                    if type(val) == "number" then
                        print("Cylinder "..prop..": "..tostring(val))
                    elseif type(val) == "table" then
                        print("Cylinder "..prop..": "..tostring(val.x..", "..val.y..", "..val.z))
                    end
                end
                print("\n")
            end;
            ContainsVector = function(self, vector)
                --vector is between top and bottom
                if vector.y < self.Top and vector.y > self.Bottom then
                    local x0 = self.Center.x
                    local z0 = self.Center.z
                    local r = self.Radius
                    local x1 = vector.x
                    local z1 = vector.z
                    local cont = math.sqrt((x1-x0)*(x1-x0) + (z1-z0)*(z1-z0)) < r
                    return cont
                end
                return false
            end
        }
    end;
}



function main()
    local pos = Vector3.new(-2.5, 7.5, -80.7)
    local pos2 = Vector3.new(9.3, 2.5, -60.5)

    local region = CylinderRegion:New(Vector3.new(13.9, 14.2, 16.7), 28.4, 61)

    print("Created new cylinder with the following properties:\n")
    region:PrintProperties()

    local ex = region:ContainsVector(pos)
    local ex2 = region:ContainsVector(pos2)
    if ex then
        print("pos ("..tostring(pos.x..", "..pos.y..", "..pos.z)..") is inside the cylinder!")
    else
        print("pos ("..tostring(pos.x..", "..pos.y..", "..pos.z)..") is NOT inside the cylinder!")
    end
    if ex2 then
        print("pos2 ("..tostring(pos2.x..", "..pos2.y..", "..pos2.z)..") is inside the cylinder!")
    else
        print("pos2 ("..tostring(pos2.x..", "..pos2.y..", "..pos2.z)..") is NOT inside the cylinder!")
    end
end



local s, e = pcall(main)
if not s then
    print(e)
end
io.read()
```

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I narrowed the problem down to 8 lines in my question, I just added the entire table for readability and understanding

Comment: Understand. But you should give input & expected output & output including intermediate values. Also the problem might not where you think.

Comment: How is pos inside the cylinder with z value -80?

Answer (score 0):

Your formulas look right, it's your data.

You say `pos` @ -2.5, 7.5, -80.7 is within the cylinder, but it *cannot* be since the min/max of z for the cylinder is -44.3 to +77.7.